# How to change the order of execution of test steps in Allure

Tags: java, maven, testing, allure

I'm using java,testng,maven,allure framework.
While test is running i have unsorted order of steps execution:
1. method1
2. createReport
3. performLogin
4. verifyProject

But i want to change order to method 1 -> performLogin -> verifyProject -> createReport

```
public void method1 () throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
    //some code
}

@Step ("Perform login to ...")
public void performLogin () throws InterruptedException {
    //action
}

@Step ("Verify that current project is correct")
public void verifyProject () throws InterruptedException {
   //action
}

@Step("Go to creation of new Report")
public void createReport () throws InterruptedException {
    //action
}
```

Comment: Why don't you explicitly call test step methods inside your test method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to testng and allure.
So i wrote @Test under the class that's why it was executed in random order.

Solution is:
create one new method with @Test and use methods with steps(@Step) in needed order and remove @Test from class.